How to read the configuration from one python file in another python file
I have a .py file as below:
dict_nova = {
    "export_nova_rosterlight":{
    "metadata_resource_id": "export_nova_rosterlight",
    "metadata_product_version" : "1.0",
    "List_Fields": [
        "data_export",
        "userID",
        "deviceName",
        "osVersion",
        "emailAddress",
        "model",
        "serialNumber"]
    },
    "export_nova_export":{
    "metadata_resource_id":"Export_nova_export",
    "metadata_product_version" : "1.0",
    "List_Fields": [ "data_export",
                    "userMail",
                    "userID",
                    "deviceName",
                    "emailAddress"]
                }   
}

In another .py file I have a function to validate some columns based on some conditions as below:
def validate_counts(df):
    distinct_mail = df.agg(F.countDistinct('emailAddress')).collect()[0][0]
    distinctdevice = df.agg(F.countDistinct('deviceName')).collect()[0][0]
    
    if 10000 <= distinct_mail <= 20000 and 5000 <= distinctdevice <= 10000:
        result = 'valid'
    else:
        result = 'invalid'
        
    return result

But I need to validate the columns from the "export_nova_rosterlight" key from the other .py file. How to do this.

In the second file, do from firstfile import dict_nova.  What is the difficulty?

You're missing the parameter list of the function. Even if there are no parameters, you need an empty list: def validate_counts():

You can modify the validate_counts function to take dict_nova as an argument. This way all information from the dictionary can be used for the validation process.

The question is about how to get the information from one script into the other.
